# SQLITE: Count column values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some code like this:

```
    public void gameOverCheck() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("SELECT " + COL_ROLE + " COUNT");
    database.close();
}
```

in android. And would like to count the values of COL_ROLE (which has one of two possible values (mafia, civilian)). So if the number of Mafia >= Civilian game = mafias win. If Mafias = 0, game = civilian won. I am struggling with the SQL command to do the first part, am I supposed to group the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(*) from your_table where " + COL_ROLE + " = 'mafia'", null);
mCount.moveToFirst();
int count = mCount.getInt(0);
mCount.close();`
```

Comment: Thank you :), what do you mean by it will be stored in the Count variable? How would I retrieve this variable and say, store it into a String or an Int?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the execSql method doesn't return any data - I've updated my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you :) So I now have Cursors which count both the Mafias and Civilians using your code, stored in countM and countC respectively. I need an if else statement now to compare the two ints and I should be set! Thanks!